# Can not get data from SQLite database

Tags: android, sqlite

I've managed to insert data in SQLiteDatabase using this code

```
    void addAlarm(Alarms alarms) {
        Log.i("Point","process is starting");
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(COLUMN_ALARM, alarms.getAlarm());

        // Inserting Row
        db.insert(TABLE_ALARMS, null, values);
        db.close(); // Closing database connection
        Log.i("Point","inserting is done in addAlarm method");
    }
```

But then I want to get data using this method:

```
    Long getAlarm(int id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_ALARMS, new String[]{COLUMN_ID,
                        COLUMN_ALARM}, COLUMN_ID + "=?",
                new String[]{String.valueOf(id)}, null, null, null, null);
        Long l = null;
        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
           l = cursor.getLong(1);
        }
        // return contact
        return l;
    }
```

And after I want to know that the data is still in the database, I use this code:

```
mySQLiteHelper = new MySQLiteHelper(context);
        Log.i("Point",Long.toString(mySQLiteHelper.getAlarm(0)));
        Log.i("Point",Long.toString(mySQLiteHelper.getAlarm(1)));
```

And at that point I got NullPointerException at logcat. **Can somebody explain why this is going on and what should I do with this???**

And also when I want to delete it I get no errors or exceptions.
This is code for deleting data:

```
public void deleteAlarm(int id) {
        Log.i("Point","deleting is starting");
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete(TABLE_ALARMS, COLUMN_ID + " = ?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(id) });
        db.close();
        Log.i("Point","deleting is over");
    }
```

Thank you.

**EDIT**

My whole code:

```
public class MySQLiteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final String TABLE_ALARMS = "alarms";
    public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
    public static final String COLUMN_ALARM = "alarm";
    public static final String DB_PATH = "/DATA/data/db1/databases/";

    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "alarms.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    // Database creation sql statement
    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table "
            + TABLE_ALARMS + "(" + COLUMN_ID
            + " integer primary key autoincrement, " + COLUMN_ALARM
            + " text not null);";

    public MySQLiteHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
        database.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        //Log.w(MySQLiteHelper.class.getName(),
        //        "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
        //                + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_ALARMS);
        onCreate(db);
    }
    void addAlarm(Alarms alarms) {
        Log.i("Point","process is starting");
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(COLUMN_ALARM, alarms.getAlarm());

        // Inserting Row
        db.insert(TABLE_ALARMS, null, values);
        db.close(); // Closing database connection
        Log.i("Point","inserting is done in addAlarm method");
    }

    // Getting single contact
    Long getAlarm(int id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_ALARMS, new String[]{COLUMN_ID,
                        COLUMN_ALARM}, COLUMN_ID + "=?",
                new String[]{String.valueOf(id)}, null, null, null, null);
        Long l = null;
        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
           l = cursor.getLong(1);
        }
        // return contact
        return l;
    }
    public void deleteAlarm(int id) {
        Log.i("Point","deleting is starting");
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete(TABLE_ALARMS, COLUMN_ID + " = ?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(id) });
        db.close();
        Log.i("Point","deleting is over");
    }
}
```

Errors:

```
Process: com.example.amadey.myapplication, PID: 1509
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.example.amadey.myapplication.EndReceiver: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2414)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1272)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.example.amadey.myapplication.EndReceiver.onReceive(EndReceiver.java:20)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2407)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1272)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

And Alarms.class:

```
public class Alarms{
    private int id;
    private String alarms;
    private Long alarm;

    public Alarms(int id,Long l){
        this.alarm = l;
        this.id = id;
    }
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Long getAlarm() {
        return alarm;
    }

    public void setAlarms(String alarms) {
        this.alarms = alarms;
    }
}

public class EndReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    MySQLiteHelper mySQLiteHelper;
    public EndReceiver() {
    }
```

EndReceiver.class

```
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        context.stopService(new Intent(context, MyService.class));
        context.stopService(new Intent(context, MyService2.class));
        mySQLiteHelper = new MySQLiteHelper(context);
        Log.i("Point",Long.toString(mySQLiteHelper.getAlarm(0)));
        Log.i("Point",Long.toString(mySQLiteHelper.getAlarm(1)));
        Log.i("Point", "next step is deleting");
        mySQLiteHelper.deleteAlarm(0);
        mySQLiteHelper.deleteAlarm(1);
        Log.i("Point","deleting is done");

        mySQLiteHelper.close();
        /*Intent intent1 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        intent1.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
        intent1.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
        intent1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(intent1);*/
    }
}
```

Comment: If the id is INT type in your database, then your result is coming back empty because you are searching for a string.

Comment: When you did `CREATE TABLE`, I assume one column is `COLUMN_ID INT`? Then why are you converting it to a string with `COLUMN_ID + "=?", new String[] {String.valueOf(id)}`

Comment: @cricket-007 No no no, COLUMN_ID is string

Comment: @cricket-007 This is how I initialize COLUMN_ID: public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id"; Did you mean this?

Comment: No, in your `CREATE TABLE` statement. You did actually create a SQLite table before you started querying data, yes?

Comment: @cricket-007 Yes, I create table before doing anything with SQLite

Comment: And you still have not answered the question as to whether in the `CREATE TABLE` statement is `COLUMN_ID` is `INT` or `TEXT`. Please edit your question to create a full [mcve] and include the error message for your NullPointerException.

Comment: @cricket-007 I've edited question, take a look

Comment: This isn't your whole code. Where is `EndReceiver`? That is where your error is happening.

Comment: @cricket-007 Added EndReciever.class

Comment: And line 20 of that class is what?

Comment: @cricket-007 These are lines 20 and 21 : Log.i("Point",Long.toString(mySQLiteHelper.getAlarm(0)));
Log.i("Point",Long.toString(mySQLiteHelper.getAlarm(1)));

Answer (score 1):

So, several things I see going on are...

1. Your table is defined with two columns, `COLUMN_ID integer` and `COLUMN_ALARM text`
2. Your Alarm object has three fields. An `int id`, a `String alarms`, and a `Long alarm`. I assume the `String alarms` is the value you are wanting to insert into the database since the column is of type `text`.
3. `alarms.getAlarm()` is returning the `Long` object, and not the String, and yet you are trying to insert a `Long` value into a `text` column with `values.put(COLUMN_ALARM, alarms.getAlarm());`...
4. Your actual problem is that `l = cursor.getLong(1);` is **returning null** because according to the documentation `getLong()` will "throw an exception when the column value is null, the column type is not an integral type"

In general, if you don't understand why you are using the `Long` object, you should be using the primitive `long` instead.

To fix your problem, though, I suggest you consider doing some of the following

1. Ensure data is actually being stored in the database.
2. Fix the column types of your `CREATE TABLE` statement to make `COLUMN_ALARM` an `integer` type for storing `Long` values that you can query correctly.
3. Use `cursor.getString(1)` instead of `cursor.getLong(1)` to retrieve the `TEXT` column
4. Define a `String getAlarms()` method to actually return the `String alarms` value and insert that into the database instead of the `Long` object with `values.put(COLUMN_ALARM, alarms.getAlarms());`

Comment: @cricket-007 Can you please tell me how to set query in addAllarm method if COLUMN_ALARM is integer?

Comment: You aren't doing a query in `addAlarm`. You are doing an `insert`. It should be the exact same as you were doing it before.

Comment: @cricket-007 Ohhh, sorry, I meant getAlarm method

Comment: If the column is an integer, then you do `int i = -1;` and then `i = cursor.getInt(1)` (or whatever column it is).